# Hardhat doesn't recognize functions

Tags: hardhat

I have a simple contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/finance/VestingWalletUpgradeable.sol';

contract VestingWallet is VestingWalletUpgradeable {

    function initialize(address beneficiaryAddress, uint64 startTimestamp, uint64 durationSeconds) external initializer {
        __VestingWallet_init(beneficiaryAddress, startTimestamp, durationSeconds);
    }
}
```

In my tests I cannot call some methods on the [contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/master/contracts/finance/VestingWalletUpgradeable.sol):

```
# these do work
expect(await wallet.beneficiary()).to.eq(beneficiaryAddress);
expect(await wallet.start()).to.eq(now);
expect(await wallet.duration()).to.eq(2);

# this (and others) do not work
expect(await wallet.released()).to.eq(utils.parseEther("0"));
```

The error is

`error TS2551: Property 'released' does not exist on type 'VestingWallet'. Did you mean 'released()'?`

I already found out that it seems like the ones that do not work are in quotes in the generated types (green works, red does not):

[image]

What does therefore work is

`expect(await wallet["released()"]()).to.eq(utils.parseEther("0"));`

Why is that the case and how to circumvent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that just the name of the function is not uniqued. E.g. you have a `released` without parameters and with an address parameter. Therefore you need to specify which one to use. As far as I know ethers cannot automatically detect this (also because there are cases where this is ambiguous, e.g. `example(address)` and `example(uint160)`). If you make sure that each of these functions is unique the default way will work again.

More details on this: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/407